# How to import a python file inside a folder?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, python-import

Im having trouble importing a python file that is in the seme directory but on a folder: ./subproject1/subproject1.py
Error:

> File "/home/ubuntu4/Downloads/ProjectX/main.py", line 4, in 
> import subproject1.subproject1
> ImportError: No module named subproject1.subproject1

The project looks like this:

```
/home/ubuntu4/Downloads/ProjectX
      -/subproject1
           - subproject1.py
      main.py
```

And I import like this on python:

```
import sys 
import os
import multiprocessing
import subproject1.subproject1
```

I have runned this from my windows PC and it works perfectly and from my ubuntu pc it isn't working, some suggestions?

Comment: how did you run on python, use command line or some ide?

Comment: **python main.py** directly from terminal inside a VENV

Comment: Try to add an empty `__init__.py` file in `subproject1` directory.

Comment: There where no changes, same error

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug since I restarted the computer, without any changes and the problem was solved, when working with a virtual environment in a virtual machine it may have generated a bug